# How to change get method to post method for sending sms in php

Tags: php, curl

Pls mention how to change below mentioned lines to POST method to send sms..

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://xxxxxxx.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=$user&pass=$pwd&sender=$sender&phone=$pno&text=".urlencode($_REQUEST['MESSAGE'])."&priority=ndnd&stype=normal");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work :

```
$toPost = array("user" => $user,
                "pass" => $pwd,
                "sender" => $sender,
                "phone" => $pno,
                "text" => urlencode($_REQUEST['MESSAGE']),
                "priority" => "ndnd",
                "stype" => "normal"
                );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://xxxxxxx.com/api/sendmsg.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // If you use this line, you will get response from API in $result below.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $toPost);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The response returned by the API is in the `$result` variable.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Roxinagi...